# Calling PHP Class Public Function Inside Smarty Template

Tags: php, smarty

Can someone help me out here.

How can i Call a PHP class public function inside a Smarty template file for example.

I have 2 Functions inside the Movie Class

```
GetAllMovies(); // Gets all Movies
```

and

```
GetMovie($movie_id); // Gets movie by movie id
```

Now i am calling the `GetAllMovies();` and assigning it to the template

```
<?php
  include 'movie.class.php';
  $movie = new Movie();

  $movies = $movie->GetAllMovies();
  $smarty->assign('movies',$movies);
<?
```

Now inside the template file i've got a `foreach` statement for the movies.

```
{foreach from=$movies key=key item=mov}
  // Access Movie ID, Title And Images 
{/foreach}
```

Now what i want to do is to call `GetMovie($movie_id);` inside this `foreach` statement for example do something like this.

Assign Movie class to Smarty Template.

```
$smarty->assign('movie',$movie);
```

Then use `$movie` to call the function for example

```
{foreach from=$movies key=key item=mov}
  {assign var=movie_info value=$movie::GetMovie($mov.id)}
  {$movie_info.rating} 
{/foreach}
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Seems you do not understand what MVC is all about.

Comment: I dont know about smarty template but in your exemple you use `$movie::GetMovie($mov_id)` isn't it suppose to be `$movie->GetMovie($mov_id)`? (considering `::` calls a static function)

Comment: Why the down vote this is a genuine question and i asked for Smarty i don't want to know about MVC

Comment: @Sebastien Well that is what i thought but smarty's example shows different

Comment: @Seven00MB As I already said I dont know about Smarty Template but I do know PHP and I would think you'd have to use a normal call for that function unless its static. But I dont think this is the problem here it was just an observation.

Answer (score 3):

It looks realy creepy but if you realy want to use it in that way, I suggest to create array on PHP side and assing it to smarty like:

```
$movies = array();
$movie = new Movie();
foreach ($movie->GetAllMovies() as $key => $movieDetails) {
    $mov = new Movie();
    $movies[] = $mov->getMovie($movieDetails['id']);
}

$smarty->assign('movies',$movies);
```

and in smarty you can loop thrue your $movies array

```
{foreach from=$movies key=key item=mov}
    {$mov.rating} 
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on this:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.static.classes.tpl

This should work:

```
{assign var=movie_info value=Movie::GetMovie($mov.id)}
```

At least if it is an existing static method...

Comment: I do think its a valid answer but I dont think this is a 'good' way of using a static method.

Comment: +1 I do agree that it is probably not the best use of a static class. Nevertheless, it is an actual example from the Smarty site and therefore a valid solution. I can't see a downvote on an endorsed example as logical...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't tell you how to do it because it doesn't make any sense for me.

Template engine is for displaying data and you should get data inside Model/Controller. You should assign to Smarty data that is prepared to display and in Smarty you should display it.

So in your case before:

```
$smarty->assign('movies',$movies);
```

you should use:

```
$movies = $movie->GetAllMovies();
foreach ($movies as $k => $v) {
   $movies[$k]['details'] = $movie->GetMovie($v['id');
}
```

and then in Smarty:

```
{foreach from=$movies key=key item=mov}
  {$mov.details.rating} 
{/foreach}
```

However if I were you, I would consider getting data. I assume that you get your movies from Database, so using:

```
$movies = $movie->GetAllMovies(); // 1 query
foreach ($movies as $k => $v) {
   $movies[$k]['details'] = $movie->GetMovie($v['id'); // n queries
}
```

you run `n+1` queries to your database, where `n` is number of movies.

It's quite possible that instead of this, you could run one query to database (depending on your structure using join or even not) so you should rethink if you get data the best way it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way to do it, would be pulling your movies data in a 'ready-to-display' form, such as an array, associative array or their multidimensional counterparts that smarty can handle right away with the {foreach} tag. Maybe something that looked like:

```
array ( 
    0 => array ( 0 => 'PHP the Movie 1', 1 => '2009', 2 => 'Coder 1', 3 => '3', ), 
    1 => array ( 0 => 'PHP the Movie 2', 1 => '2010', 2 => 'Coder 2', 3 => '2', ), 
    2 => array ( 0 => 'PHP the Movie 3', 1 => '2011', 2 => 'Coder 3', 3 => '1', ), 
)
array ( 
    0 => array ( 
        'title' => 'PHP the Movie 1', 
        'year' => '2009', 
        'director' => 'Coder 1', 
        'rating' => '3', ), 
    1 => array ( 
        'title' => 'PHP the Movie 2', 
        'year' => '2010', 
        'director' => 'Coder 2', 
        'rating' => '2', ), 
    2 => array ( 
        'title' => 'PHP the Movie 3', 
        'year' => '2011', 
        'director' => 'Coder 3', 
        'rating' => '1', ), 
)


array ( 
    0 => array ( 
        'title' => 'PHP the Movie 1', 
        'year' => '2009', 
        'director' => 'Coder 1', 
        'rating' => '3', ), 
    1 => array ( 
        'title' => 'PHP the Movie 2', 
        'year' => '2010', 
        'director' => 'Coder 2', 
        'rating' => '2', ), 
    2 => array ( 
        'title' => 'PHP the Movie 3', 
        'year' => '2011', 
        'director' => 'Coder 3', 
        'rating' => '1', ), 
)
```

Only my humble opinion but I actually use it at work both to display data-sets with smarty and to build JSON responses for AJAX requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use static methods in your movie class.

If for example your class is named "MovieClass" then you could have:

```
MovieClass::GetMovie($mov.id);
```

To create a static method just use the following format when declaring the method inside your class

```
public static GetMovie($mov.id)
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that?
I think it's a good use of a static method. He needs some functionality that is related to the Movie class, so it belongs there as a static function.

Comment: A static method can be called without instanciating an object of the class so if there isn't a object of `MovieClass` `GetMovie()` would cause trouble. The only way this you be a 'good' use of a static method is if you want to return Every movie for all the instances of `MovieClass`.

Comment: No it would not. It has a parameter `movieId` in order to specify which movie do you want, so it doesn't need an instance of the MovieClass object.

Comment: Except In that case is not the function that is bad is the OOP... -EDIT- the programming is bad (OOP) not the OP(just to be clear)

Comment: And furthermore for this function to be valid, it would need something like a private attribut that is a collection of instances or movie_id so it can return the movie ask by the parameter. Which than wouldn't be a `MovieClass` but more of a `LibraryMovieClass`. Even than it would still need (to make oop sense) to have a `MovieClass` to instanciate movie otherwise its not good practise OOP...

Comment: OP needs a function that takes a `movieId` and returns a movie.

The best thing he could do is create a constructor that takes a `movieId` and returns an instance of `Movie`.

If he does that the `GetAllMovies` function should become a static one, because it is not associated with the `Movie` instance, but it is associated with the class.

My suggestion for `GetMovie` to become a static function is just a quick fix for the problem, but not the best one.